# The class $l(F)$ of morphisms which have the left lifting property with respect to $F$ is stable under transfinite compositions.

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

I am reading Cisinski's *Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra* and I am having trouble trying to verify some claims there. My background in category theory is not very solid. I would like some help to understand and prove one of that claims.

> Let $i: A \to B$ and $p: X \to Y$ be two morphisms in a category
> $\mathcal{C}$. We say that $i$ has the left lifting property with
> respect to $p$, or, equivalently, that $p$ has the right lifting
> property with respect to $i$, if any commutative square of the form
>
> [image]
>
> has a diagonal filler
>
> [image]
>
> (i.e. a morphism $h$ such that $hi = a$ and $ph = b$).
>
> A class of morphisms $F$, in a category $\mathcal{C}$, is stable under
> *transfinite compositions* if, for any well ordered set $I$, with initial element $0$, for any functor $X: I \to \mathcal{C}$ such that,
> for any element $i \in I$, $i \neq 0$, the colimit $\varinjlim_{j < i} X(j)$ is representable and the induced map
> $$\varinjlim_{j < i} X(j) \to X(i)$$ belongs to the class $F$, the colimit $\varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$ exists and the canonical morphism $X(0) \to \varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$ belongs to $F$ as well.
>
> **Proposition:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with a class of morphisms $F$. Then the class $l(F)$ is stable under transfinite compositions.

The above proposition is just a small part of the Proposition 2.1.4 in the book. I was able to prove the other parts, so I am not completely lost. The problem is in this definition of transfinite composition... I know what a colimit is, I know what a well ordered set is, but I am not sure I understood the definition at all. Where does the condition "the colimit $\varinjlim_{j < i} X(j)$ is representable" comes into play? What is the canonical morphism $X(0) \to \varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$? Is this one of that morphisms in the definition of cocone? How does the above definition is equivallent to the [nLab definition](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/transfinite+composition) of transfinite composition? How to prove the above Proposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisinski means that the colimit *exists*, in more common terminology for English-speaking mathematicians. (In the Grothendieck school, it is traditional to speak of a colimit as a presheaf, so that it always exists, and the question is whether this presheaf is representable in the starting category.)

Now, as for what the condition says: first, consider the case that $i=i'+1$ is a successor ordinal. Then $\mathrm{colim}_{j<i}X(j)=X(i'),$ and so the condition simply says that the map $X(i')\to X(i)$ is in $F.$ The case in which $i$ is a limit ordinal is the natural way to say what is morally the same thing: for instance, the map $\mathrm{colim}_{i\in\omega} X(i)\to X(\omega)$ is in $F.$ If you're homotopy-theoretically minded you might picture this as the union of a countable chain of cofibrations, all mapping into $X(\omega).$

Yes, the canonical morphism from $X(0)$ to the colimit must be the appropriate leg of the colimiting cocone.

With all this spelled out, the proposition should be easy to prove by transfinite induction.

Comment: I am not homotopy-theoretically minded, but I think I got it now. I have to use the UMP of colimits to inductively draw the red dashed arrows in this figure: https://imgur.com/p6TOa8K
Right?

Comment: I'm still having trouble trying to prove that $\varinjlim_{ i \in I} X(i)$ exists when $I$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: That the colimit exists is an assumption, not something to be proved.

Comment: I thought I could only assume that each colimit $\varinjlim_{j < i} X(j)$, with $i \in I - \{0\}$, was representable. Look at the part "the colimit $\varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$ exists and the canonical morphism $X(0) \to \varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$ belongs to $F$ as well." I thought this was the conclusion I needed to prove. If the existence of $\varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$ was an assumption, then that quote should be  "and the colimit $\varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$ exists, then the canonical morphism $X(0) \to \varinjlim_{i \in I} X(i)$ belongs to $F$ as well."

Comment: Oh, yes, I responded too quickly. This seems to be a small error. For instance if $F$ is the class of isomorphisms then $l(F)$ is all maps, but of course one can’t get, say, colimits indexed by $\omega$ in an arbitrary category for free.

Comment: Thank you! Another person answered essentially the same thing. It's comforting to know that the difficulty in proving that wasn't just my fault.