# Colimits of a diagram over an ordinal number

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

The context for my question is the following:

[The class $l(F)$ of morphisms which have the left lifting property with respect to $F$ is stable under transfinite compositions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351159/the-class-lf-of-morphisms-which-have-the-left-lifting-property-with-respect)

I was able to prove that $\varinjlim_{i < \mu} X(i) = X(\lambda)$ whenever $\mu = \lambda + 1$. I suspect that $\varinjlim_{i < \mu} X(i) = X(\mu)$ when $\mu$ is a limit ordinal, but I don't know how to prove it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Good guess, but unless you assume your diagram is “continuous” there is no reason for it to be true.

Comment: @Zhen Lin, but now, how can I prove that $\varinjlim_{i<\mu} X(i)$ exists?

Comment: What are your assumptions?

Comment: @Zhen Lin the assumptions are quoted in the linked question

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351159/the-class-lf-of-morphisms-which-have-the-left-lifting-property-with-respect

Comment: It appears to me the existence of the colimit is assumed.

Comment: @ZhenLin  He says that, for each $i \in I$, $i \neq 0$, the the colimit $\varinjlim_{j < i}X(j)$ is representable (exists). But I have to prove that $\varinjlim_{i \in I}X(i)$ is representable.

Comment: Let $I$ be a well ordered set with initial element $0$ and $X: I \to \mathcal{C}$ be a functor such that, for any element $i \in I$, $i \neq 0$, the colimit $\varinjlim_{j<i} X(j)$ is representable and the induced map $\varinjlim_{j<i} X(j) \to X(i)$ belongs to $l(F)$. Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $I$ is an ordinal number, say $I = \mu$. We have to prove that the colimit $\varinjlim_{i < \mu} X(i)$ exists and the canonical morphism $X(0) \to \varinjlim_{ i < \mu} X(i)$ belongs to $l(F)$.

Comment: I believe the statement is not written clearly. _If_ the colimit $\varinjlim_i X (i)$ exists _then_ $X (0) \to \varinjlim_i X (i)$ belongs to the class. You can't get existence of the colimit for free.

Comment: Thank you, it's comforting to know that the difficulty in proving that wasn't just my fault.